# SQL Results for Duplicates - Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

SO community, here's my SQL query which runs with no error:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    (L.LOCATION) AS "LOC",
    C.CITY_NAME AS "CIT",
    H.STREET_NAME AS "STR",
    U.APT_NAME AS "APT",
    U.NUM AS "NUM",
    L.DESCRIPTION AS "DES",
    H.POP AS "POP",
    S.STATE_CODE AS "STA",
    H.SITE_NAME AS "SIT",
    U.COUNTY AS "COU",
    L.DESCRIPTION AS "PRO"
FROM
    LOCATIONS L
    LEFT OUTER JOIN CGZIP9 Z
    ON L.L_ZIPCODE = Z.ZIPCODE
    LEFT OUTER JOIN STREET_V H
    ON L.LOCATION = H.LOCATION
    LEFT OUTER JOIN CGZIPCITY Y
    ON Z.CITYID = Y.CITYID
    LEFT OUTER JOIN CGCITY C
    ON Y.CITYID = C.CITYID
    LEFT OUTER JOIN CGSTATE S
    ON C.STATEFIPS = S.STATEFIPS
    LEFT OUTER JOIN UNIT U
    ON L.UNITID = U.UNIT_ID
WHERE
    L.LOCATION IN ('1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '1', '2', '4')
    ORDER BY L.LOCATION ASC;
```

I'm trying to retrieve records for all values in my IN (even the duplicates such as '1', '2', & '4')

Here's my output when I run the above code:

```
=============================================
|LOC|CIT|STR|APT|NUM|DES|POP|STA|SIT|COU|PRO|
=============================================
| 1 | X | X | X | X | X | X | X | X | X | X | 
| 2 | X | X | X | X | X | X | X | X | X | X |
| 3 | X | X | X | X | X | X | X | X | X | X |  
| 4 | X | X | X | X | X | X | X | X | X | X | 
| 5 | X | X | X | X | X | X | X | X | X | X |  
=============================================
```

Here's my desired output:

```
=============================================
|LOC|CIT|STR|APT|NUM|DES|POP|STA|SIT|COU|PRO|
=============================================
| 1 | X | X | X | X | X | X | X | X | X | X | 
| 2 | X | X | X | X | X | X | X | X | X | X |
| 3 | X | X | X | X | X | X | X | X | X | X |  
| 4 | X | X | X | X | X | X | X | X | X | X | 
| 5 | X | X | X | X | X | X | X | X | X | X |  
| 1 | X | X | X | X | X | X | X | X | X | X | 
| 2 | X | X | X | X | X | X | X | X | X | X |  
| 4 | X | X | X | X | X | X | X | X | X | X |  
=============================================
```

Any suggestions as to how I can accomplish this?

Comment: drop the 'distinct' from your select? And having a value twice in your `in` statement has won't make any difference on what rows are returned

Comment: Maybe if you remove the `DISTINCT`, the query should work, showing you the records in the same way you need.

Comment: `x in (1,1)` means the same thing as `(x = 1 or x = 1)`, so you would just get rows where `x = 1`. It's like requesting *"all pets that are cats or cats"*. You don't get all the cats twice.

Answer (score 2):

Please try out the UNION ALL approach which does not filter out duplicates, as follows:

```
SELECT DISTINCT (L.LOCATION)  AS "LOC",
                C.CITY_NAME   AS "CIT",
                H.STREET_NAME AS "STR",
                U.APT_NAME    AS "APT",
                U.NUM         AS "NUM",
                L.DESCRIPTION AS "DES",
                H.POP         AS "POP",
                S.STATE_CODE  AS "STA",
                H.SITE_NAME   AS "SIT",
                U.COUNTY      AS "COU",
                L.DESCRIPTION AS "PRO"
  FROM LOCATIONS L
       LEFT OUTER JOIN CGZIP9 Z ON L.L_ZIPCODE = Z.ZIPCODE
       LEFT OUTER JOIN STREET_V H ON L.LOCATION = H.LOCATION
       LEFT OUTER JOIN CGZIPCITY Y ON Z.CITYID = Y.CITYID
       LEFT OUTER JOIN CGCITY C ON Y.CITYID = C.CITYID
       LEFT OUTER JOIN CGSTATE S ON C.STATEFIPS = S.STATEFIPS
       LEFT OUTER JOIN UNIT U ON L.UNITID = U.UNIT_ID
 WHERE L.LOCATION IN ('1',
                      '2',
                      '3',
                      '4',
                      '5')
UNION ALL
SELECT DISTINCT (L.LOCATION)  AS "LOC",
                C.CITY_NAME   AS "CIT",
                H.STREET_NAME AS "STR",
                U.APT_NAME    AS "APT",
                U.NUM         AS "NUM",
                L.DESCRIPTION AS "DES",
                H.POP         AS "POP",
                S.STATE_CODE  AS "STA",
                H.SITE_NAME   AS "SIT",
                U.COUNTY      AS "COU",
                L.DESCRIPTION AS "PRO"
  FROM LOCATIONS L
       LEFT OUTER JOIN CGZIP9 Z ON L.L_ZIPCODE = Z.ZIPCODE
       LEFT OUTER JOIN STREET_V H ON L.LOCATION = H.LOCATION
       LEFT OUTER JOIN CGZIPCITY Y ON Z.CITYID = Y.CITYID
       LEFT OUTER JOIN CGCITY C ON Y.CITYID = C.CITYID
       LEFT OUTER JOIN CGSTATE S ON C.STATEFIPS = S.STATEFIPS
       LEFT OUTER JOIN UNIT U ON L.UNITID = U.UNIT_ID
 WHERE L.LOCATION IN ('1', '2', '4')
ORDER BY L.LOCATION ASC;
```

Comment: is there a way for the query to determine the duplicates instead of me adding them to a 2nd WHERE?

Comment: Is it your requirement that you must display duplicates if they are present? In that case just remove the keyword ** DISTINCT ** and verify , as others have suggested. By default in absence of DISTINCT and GROUP BY  Oracle query will display duplicates as duplicates if they are present. If DISTINCT is there then it will remove the duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

this will work:

```
SELECT
    L.LOCATION AS "LOC",
    C.CITY_NAME AS "CIT",
    H.STREET_NAME AS "STR",
    U.APT_NAME AS "APT",
    U.NUM AS "NUM",
    L.DESCRIPTION AS "DES",
    H.POP AS "POP",
    S.STATE_CODE AS "STA",
    H.SITE_NAME AS "SIT",
    U.COUNTY AS "COU",
    L.DESCRIPTION AS "PRO"
FROM
    LOCATIONS L
    LEFT OUTER JOIN CGZIP9 Z
    ON L.L_ZIPCODE = Z.ZIPCODE
    LEFT OUTER JOIN STREET_V H
    ON L.LOCATION = H.LOCATION
    LEFT OUTER JOIN CGZIPCITY Y
    ON Z.CITYID = Y.CITYID
    LEFT OUTER JOIN CGCITY C
    ON Y.CITYID = C.CITYID
    LEFT OUTER JOIN CGSTATE S
    ON C.STATEFIPS = S.STATEFIPS
    LEFT OUTER JOIN UNIT U
    ON L.UNITID = U.UNIT_ID
WHERE
    L.LOCATION IN ('1', '2', '3', '4', '5')
UNION ALL
SELECT 
    L.LOCATION AS "LOC",
    C.CITY_NAME AS "CIT",
    H.STREET_NAME AS "STR",
    U.APT_NAME AS "APT",
    U.NUM AS "NUM",
    L.DESCRIPTION AS "DES",
    H.POP AS "POP",
    S.STATE_CODE AS "STA",
    H.SITE_NAME AS "SIT",
    U.COUNTY AS "COU",
    L.DESCRIPTION AS "PRO"
FROM
    LOCATIONS L
    LEFT OUTER JOIN CGZIP9 Z
    ON L.L_ZIPCODE = Z.ZIPCODE
    LEFT OUTER JOIN STREET_V H
    ON L.LOCATION = H.LOCATION
    LEFT OUTER JOIN CGZIPCITY Y
    ON Z.CITYID = Y.CITYID
    LEFT OUTER JOIN CGCITY C
    ON Y.CITYID = C.CITYID
    LEFT OUTER JOIN CGSTATE S
    ON C.STATEFIPS = S.STATEFIPS
    LEFT OUTER JOIN UNIT U
    ON L.UNITID = U.UNIT_ID
WHERE
    L.LOCATION IN ('1', '2', '4');
```

remove the order by and try union all.